# What is maximum memory limit for an app in PCF during the scaling or push?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have an application which require more than 30GB of memory and more than 4GB of disk space.

Can I run the app in any of cloud foundry environments (PCF or Bluemix - enterprise account)

Please help me on this query.

Comment: 30gb on a single instance?

Comment: yes. Single instance it require 30GB of RAM

Answer (score 1):

Bluemix default quota plan does not resolve your necessity, since the default plan allows only 8GB per instance (512GB max). You would need to open a ticket to change the quota plan of your organization.

Either way, to make sure about the quota plan being used by your organization, go to Manage > Account > Organization > Select Organization > Edit Org

In the quota section, look at the [quota plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAzpG.jpg) then login into cf tool and list the quota details:

```
cf login
cf quota QUOTA_PLAN
```

This [link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/admin/manageorg.html#managequota) can give you a little more help.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on the Cloud Foundry provider that you're using and the limits that they put in place.

Behind the scenes, it also depends on the types of VMs being used for Diego Cells in the platform.  The Cells are where your application code will run and there must be enough space on a Cell to run your app instance.  As an example, if you have a total of 16G of RAM on your Diego Cells then it wouldn't be possible for a provider to support your use case of 30G for one application instance since there would be no Cells with that much free space.  If you had Cells with 32G of RAM, that might work, depending on overhead and placement of other apps, but you'd probably need something even larger like 64G per Cell.

I mention all this because at the end of the day, if you're willing to run your own Cloud Foundry installation you can pretty much do whatever you want, so running with 30G or 100G isn't a problem as long as you configure and scale your platform accordingly.

Hope that helps!